# With Interface Builder create subview with own NIB and UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, nib

I would like to create a subview of an existing view, where the subview has its own XIB-file and its own ViewController. I know that is only a view lines of code programmatically, but I really want to learn how to use Interface Builder better. Does anybody know how to do this in XCode-4 / Interface Builder?

Or, stated differently, suppose I have created one nib with my main user interface in it (let's say "main.xib"). Now I create a second view NIB "second.xib", which is linked to its own viewcontroller ("secondViewController.m"). How do I tell IB to add the second view as a subview in the main.xib?

Comment: I have read your question 8 times and have absolutely no idea what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @lawicko I have added a clarification, hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can make a new view controller or view, with it's own xib, and then go back to your original controller's xib, add a new "subview" and change the class of your subview to that new view controller.

But that's just a part of what you need. I'm afraid there is no way to do this completely with IB

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you be more specific? I can drag a new view from the library to the existing view, and it becomes a subview. But I cannot change the class of that subview into my viewcontroller. How do I tell IB that that subview is described by a separate NIB and associated view controller?

Comment: When you select that new view, go to the Identity tab, and not Attributes. From there, you can change the view's class from standard UIView to another custom UIView class (I don't know if you can assign it a new UIViewController derived class, I only did this with another UIView class). Then, in your viewDidLoad you load the new NIB ([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNewView" owner:self options:nil]). When you'll access that view controller, the subview should act just like the custom one

Comment: I am sorry, but IB only allows me to change the class into another View derived class, not into a viewController.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I did this only for a custom UIView. Again, it is not possible to do exactly what you want, my answer only covers what you can do and it's somewhat related to what you're searching for, sorry.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. I will just stick with adding it programmatically for now.

Comment: You're looking for 'view controller containment' for what it's worth.